# Responsive Image when resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

i'm create a page for web survey using boostrap, because i want my design still same in laptop/computer when access in Tablet or handphone.

But i have found problem, when resize browser

This my web when size browser >= 995px
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But when resize <= 990px

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I don't know solution how to fix this problem

This is my code

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 lk-back">

                </div>
        </div>
```

In codepen

Help me thank's

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using (3 or 4)?

Comment: @Pete bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a is not a block element by default.

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

But you should not apply bootstrap classes to your normal elements. Use the bootstrap classes just for the layout to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try `img-responsive` class in the `img` tag

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="path/to/image" />
```